# Проклятье массива на php

Tags: php

Помогите новичку не могу понять как записать в массив в цикле значение, записываю таким вот образом

```
$arrPos[] = array($arFields["ID"]);
```

в итоге массив через print_r выводит

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 316767
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 381636
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 488928
        )

)
```

как мне правильно записывать в массив чтоб на выходе у меня получилось

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 316767
    [1] => 381636
    [2] => 488928
)
```

`$arrPos = array($arFields["ID"]);` записывает только последнее значение

Comment: `$arrPos[] = array($arFields["ID"]);` надо записать так: `$arrPos[] = $arFields["ID"];`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно писать так - $arr[] = 123 и он автоматически запишет в конец

Пример -

```
$arr = [];

    $test = [123, 125, 1211];

    foreach($test as $item) {

      $arr[] = $item;

    };

    var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

$arrPos[] = array($arFields["ID"]); - проблема в том, что вы делаете следующее:

Вы определили переменную $arrPos , как массив. Далее говорите что нужно записать в первую свободную( ближайшую ячейку ) массив, в котором будет переменная $arFields["ID"].
В итоге и получается, что у вас двумерный массив.

Что бы избежать данной проблемы, просто $arrPos[] = $arFields["ID"]; - сделайте так.
Это избавит вас от лишней вложенности.

Answer (score -2):

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
```

с [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php)

Comment: просьба для минусующих: объясняйте свои минусы, пожалуйста

Comment: Не минусующий, но как код в ответе связан с вопросом?